# pattern or rule i can't remember

Tags: c#, design-patterns, rule

I read a long time ago about a rule that using an object we shouldn't point from one class to the other due to `null` possibility.

```
 class Foo
 {
   public Bar Bar1 {get; set;}

   public Foo()
   {

   }

 }

 class Bar
 {
     public string Name{ get; set;}
 }


 Foo foo = new Foo();
 foo.Bar1.Name;
```

what is the law or rule called after this pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

To quote some of it:

> In particular, an object should avoid invoking methods of a member
>   object returned by another method. For many modern object oriented
>   languages that use a dot as field identifier, the law can be stated
>   simply as "use only one dot". That is, the code a.b().Method() breaks
>   the law where a.Method() does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think your referring to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)